# Add small image to the canvas as numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have two black and white images as 2d `numpy` arrays. One of which is a canvas (non-zero) of size 500x500 and the second one is of size 80x80. I would like to set up x and y offsets and put the second image on top of the canvas starting with this offset. Is there a convenient way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
canvas[y:y+image.shape[0],x:x+image.shape[1]] = image
```

EDIT:fixed ordering