# Numpy – place small array at coordinate in large array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following 2D-numpy array:

```py
matrix = np.zeros((250, 250))
```

Now, at various coordinates, I want to replace not just the coordinate value but its local vicinity too with a smaller array. As exemplary replacement we can take a diamond:

```py
import skimage.morphology
star = skimage.morphology.diamond(3)  # small array / replacement

coords_r = np.random.randint(0, 250, 20)  # row coordinates
coords_c = np.random.randint(0, 250, 20)  # column coordinates
```

I came up with the following rather sloppy way and was wondering if there was a simpler / more elegant solution. Furthermore, this method will overwrite if two objects are close enough:

```py
max_r, max_c = matrix.shape
obj = star
half_obj = int((star.shape[0])/2)

for r, c in zip(coords_r, coords_c):
    
    curr_obj = obj
    start_r = r-half_obj-1
    end_r = r+half_obj
    start_c = c-half_obj-1
    end_c = c+half_obj
    
    # Check if on corners
    if r-half_obj-1 < 0:
        start_r = 0
        curr_obj = curr_obj[-r:, :]
    if r+half_obj > matrix.shape[0]:
        end_r = max_r
        curr_obj = curr_obj[:max_r-start_r, :]
    if c-half_obj-1 < 0:
        start_c = 0
        curr_obj = curr_obj[:, -c:]
    if c+half_obj > matrix.shape[1]:
        end_c = max_c
        curr_obj = curr_obj[:, :max_c-start_c]
        
    matrix[start_r:end_r, start_c:end_c] = curr_obj
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked similar question some time ago: [Add small image to the canvas as numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896837/add-small-image-to-the-canvas-as-numpy-arrays)

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
matrix_size = 250
star_size = 3

matrix = np.ones((matrix_size, matrix_size))
star = 1 - skimage.morphology.diamond(star_size)

coords_r = np.random.randint(0, matrix_size, 20)  # row coordinates
coords_c = np.random.randint(0, matrix_size, 20)  # column coordinates

for r, c in zip(coords_r, coords_c):
    matrix[max(r - star_size, 0):r + star_size + 1, max(c - star_size, 0):c + star_size + 1] *= star[max(star_size - r, 0):star_size + matrix_size - r, max(star_size - c, 0):star_size + matrix_size - c]
matrix = 1-matrix
```

And this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: there isn't really a point to do multiplication or all of the form gymnastics to end up doing in un-vectorized way

Answer (score 1):

You need to take better advantage of numpy slicing. As far as I understand the two random arrays `coords_r, coords_c` are the center coordinates around which you want to place your stars. I would

1. convert these to list of rectangular crop coordinates
2. loop over the coordinates and place the star in each slice

Something like

```
def center_to_bbox(coords, star_size):
    coords_x, coords_y = coords
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = coords_x - star_size, coords_y - star_size, coords_x + star_size + 1, 
    coords_y + star_size + 1,
    bboxes =(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return bboxes
x_coords = np.random.randint(0, 250 - 3, 20)  
y_coords = np.random.randint(0, 250 - 3 , 20)
x1, y1, x2, y2 = bboxes
for x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_ in zip(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    matrix[y1_:y2_, x1_:x2_] = star
```

Note also that you might as well subtract the dimension of the star so you don't have to compensate for it at the boundaries later

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you might want to work with [scipy sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). Just define small matrices and add them to the bigger matrix. lil_matrix seems to be the suitable format you're looking for.

Edit: @iantonuk I was thinking of the following which works well while adding/assembling matrices, but not while replacing entries.

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
data1 = ((1.0,2.0,3.0),([0,1,2],[0,1,2]))
mat1  = coo_matrix(data1,shape=(3,3))
print(mat1.todense())
data2 = ((2.0,3.0),([1,2],[1,2]))
mat2  = coo_matrix(data2,shape=(3,3))
print(mat2.todense())
mat3  = mat1 + mat2
print(mat3.todense())
```

Comment: a sample of doing that would be valuable

Answer (score 0):

Here's how easy you can do it in vectorized way:

```
def put_rounds(image:np.array, ptsx, ptsy):
    xm1, x, xp1 = (ptsx-1,ptsx,ptsx+1)
    ym1, y, yp1 = (ptsy-1,ptsy,ptsy+1)

    #make a round, r=3 or diamond pattern or whatever you need
    ptsx3 = np.dstack((xm1, xm1, ptsx,xm1,ptsx, xp1, ptsx,xm1, xp1)).flatten()
    ptsy3 = np.dstack((ym1, yp1, ym1,ptsy,ptsy, ptsy,yp1, yp1, yp1)).flatten()

    #this at least 7.5-12 times faster then loops(at least 50+ times faster on torch)
    image[ptsy3, ptsx3] = np.array([255,255,0])
```